# How to reuse code in iOS(IBAction)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've got two view controllers that have some similar function. Some of them are IBActions. Is there a way to put them together(so that it's easier to fix bugs)? I've tried inheritance but it seems that it does not work.

```
@implementation ClassA
-(IBAction)f
{
    //some code here
}

@implementation ClassB
-(IBAction)f
{
    //some code here
}
```

My question is that is there a way that I write function f once? If there is a bug, I could fix it more quickly this way.

Comment: Please clear your question and ask it properly.

Comment: You can try to use the IBActions method like void and call them with the specific (id)sender parameter (sender is for example the button1 and button2).It will check which ui element called this method. This will help you variate the method.

Comment: @vishiphone, I added some detail

Comment: @mihirios, I added some detail

Comment: Use protocol that will help you.In protocol you implement your method and call it another any class.

Comment: Is there a way to implement the method in a protocol? How to do that? @vishiphone

Comment: Yes protocol just use for method only. you can implement any method in protocol and you can call any where in class.

Comment: do one thing create one .h file and just all your method initialize in that class and in your view controller call that protocol and implement that method.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, @visiphone. My question is to reuse code. To write the same implementation only once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in inheritence, you can just declare in parent class, like abstract function, and for each child defination will be separte, now you have to do is this

make a method in parent class that performs the logic only,

make two ibactionn methods both in childs and perform the current child's UI tasks in that methods and use the parent's logic method, that u created above, to get the data.

inform if you get soltion or not.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This time I ctrl dragged both view controller in the story board to the same IBAction(in base class). This didn't work last time, but it works this time. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method that does the job and call it either from the IBAction or wherever you need it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This time I ctrl dragged both view controller in the story board to the same IBAction(in base class). This didn't work last time, but it works this time. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can make utility kind of class where you can make class method for this.
And you can call this method where needed.

Answer (score 0):

You Can make another singleton class or utility class as per your requirement. And make class method, for common functionality. So u can use this functionality any where from project.

Its good practice to make utility class or singleton class for some common functionalities.